# Are there some good Javascript templates out there?

Tags: javascript, code, layout

I am trying to create a simple .js file that will let me have some submit buttons here and there, with the text paragraph in the middle changing based on which submit button is pressed. Does the Javascript community provide either generic or specific templates that does this? It does not need to be exactly like this, just having a few submit buttons and text that changes is what matters.

Comment: Sounds like you mean HTML form templates, which are not related to javascript in any meaningful way. The term "JavaScript templates" is non existent, JavaScript is a language and has no visual representation.

Comment: Hmm I guess what I meant by "template" was some sort of pre-defined code that I could just go ahead and use. I'm not used to Javascript, but I've programmed in tons of languages that I'm sure that I can pick up from it fast just from looking at the sample code.

Comment: The best template is [vapor.js](http://vaporjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You might mean JavaScript library (or framework), there are several.
As far as I know, these are the more popular ones:

- [Yahoo's YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)
- [Sencha's ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/)
- [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/)

And probably dozens other ones, google for "JavaScript framework". Or check [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks) or [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs).

Comment: So these are basically APIs, right?

Comment: I'm using some software to create my .js files, and that software itself provides its own API.... not sure how I'd be able to incorporate the ones you gave me, but I'll try

Comment: I wouldn't call these APIs, "abstractions" might be an acceptable description.